# iOS 13 UIContextualAction completion triggers unexpected keyboard dismissal

Tags: uitableview, ios13, swift5, resignfirstresponder, uicontextualaction

I have a `UITableView` with cells that have swappable `UIContextualActions` to delete or rename (edit) individual cell's TextFields.

Since I made the switch to `Swift 5 / iOS 13`, triggering the rename `UIContextualAction` on these cells causes the keyboard to launch and instantly dismiss before the user has a chance to type.  Not only does the keyboard go away, the particular cell I'm trying to edit becomes completely empty, and the following warning gets generated:

```
[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x10c90a470, _UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

Below is the code for the rename `UIContextualAction`:

```
let actionRename = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, completionHandler) in

      let cell = self.tableLayers.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! LayerUITableViewCell
      cell.layerTitle.isEnabled = true // enable UITextField editing
      cell.layerTitle.becomeFirstResponder() // launch keyboard
      cell.layerTitle.selectedTextRange = cell.layerTitle.textRange(from: (cell.layerTitle.beginningOfDocument), to: (cell.layerTitle.endOfDocument)) // select all text
      completionHandler(true)

} // end of let actionRename
```

I'm guessing the animation of the UIContextual action is somehow triggering the keyboard's `resignFirstResponder`.

To summarize, prior to `swift 5/iOS 13`, the order of events went something like this:

1. user swipes cell left/right
2. user hits UIContextual button
3. cell returns to center
4. text gets selected
5. keyboard launches
6. user types, hits return
7. keyboard `resignFirstResponder`

Whereas the behavior I'm seeing after the migration looks like this:

1. user swipes cell left/right
2. user hits UIContextual button
3. text gets selected
4. keyboard launches
5. cell returns to center (which somehow triggers `resignFirstResponder`)
6. keyboard `resignFirstResponder`

**Update 2019/10/02**

I have confirmed that it's the cell animation that is causing the premature keyboard dismissal.  If I introduce a delay after the completionHandler as follows:

```
let actionRename = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, completionHandler) in

      completionHandler(true)
      self.perform(#selector(self.layerRenameDos), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)   
      // layerRenameDos has the editing/firstResponder code from above

    } // end of let actionRename
```

With this change, the cell animates back to center, keyboard launches, and I'm able to type away.  This, however, is obviously a hacky work-around.  Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better solution. Just be sure to execute your code on the next runloop.

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     //your code on the next runloop after the animation has finished
   }
}
complitionHandler(true)
// or tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: I implemented the changes, but saw no difference.  Perhaps I don't understand what you mean by 'next loop'.  Can you explain? Thank you.